# How can I make a variable wait for user to press one of four buttons?

Tags: java, android

Well, I'll try to be clearer.

I have a variable called `int tentativa` and i want it to receive a specific value depending on which button the user press.

I have these four buttons: `btPedra[0]`, `btPedra[1]`, `btPedra[2]`, `btPedra[3]`.

If the user press the button `btPedra[0]`, the variable will receive the number 0.

If the user press the button `btPedra[1]`, the variable will receive the number 1 and so on...

Note: The program should wait the user presses one of the buttons to proceed.

My code looks like this:

```
for (contador = 0; contador < jogada; ++contador){

    tentativa = 
    // HERE THE VARIABLE tentativa SHOULD RECEIVE 0, 1, 2 OR 3 DEPENDING ON THE BUTTON PRESSED.

    if (tentativa[contador] == sequencia[contador]){
        acertos++;
    } else {
        gameOver();
    }
}
```

When the button is pressed i want to change the background color of it too.

Note: I'm programming in java for android!

Comment: Try adding an event listener to the button/s that then performs the actions you require.

Comment: Hello. You shouldn't include `Hello`, `Thanks`, `How are you?` or any other salutations in your message. If you are interested why - read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would solve this problem slightly different.

Let's assume you define your buttons in this way:

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        ...
        android:onClick="buttonClick1"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        ...
        android:onClick="buttonClick2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        ...
        android:onClick="buttonClick3"/>
```

Then, i would add the following lines to your activity:

```
public void buttonClick1(View v) {
   gameCheck(1);
}

public void buttonClick2(View v) {
   gameCheck(2);
}

public void buttonClick3(View v) {
   gameCheck(3);
}
```

Lastly, gameCheck will be the method to check if the game is over and make the counting:

```
public void gameCheck(int tentativa) {

        if (tentativa == sequencia[current_step]){
            acertos++;
        } else {
            gameOver();
        }
        current_step++;
        contador++;
    }
}
```

Note that I am taking some variables out of gameCheck and I am assuming they're variables of this class.

A last observation regarding the style, instead of having three methods for button clicks, i would have just one and use the id to know which value shall i pass to gameCheck.

I hope it makes sense and it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
  View.OnClickListener clickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btPedra[0]:

        // if User Press Button 0/1/2/3/4 at time  you call a method 

        case R.id.btPedra[1]:
            btPedraOne();
            break;

        case R.id.btPedra[2]:
            btnPedrTwo();
            break;

        case R.id.btPedra[3]:
            btnPedrThree();
            break;
       case R.id.btPedra[4]:
            btnPedraFor();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle Click Events of **btPedra[0]**, **btPedra[1]**, **btPedra[2]**, **btPedra[3]** by setting `ClickListener` to them

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {

        case R.id.<id_of_btPedra[0]> : 
            // set variable tentativa to 0
            tentativa = 0;
            break;
        case R.id.<id_of_btPedra[1]> : 
            // set variable tentativa to 1
            tentativa = 1;
            break;
        case R.id.<id_of_btPedra[2]> : 
            // set variable tentativa to 2
            tentativa = 2;
            break;
        case R.id.<id_of_btPedra[3]> : 
            // set variable tentativa to 3
            tentativa = 3;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an onclick listener to the button and set the variable in the onclick method.

`Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
     //set the variable.

       }
       });`